# How do I programmatically modify the body field's markup/render after it's filtered "Allowed HTML tags" from "Content Authoring"?

Tags: 8

I need to modify what is being rendered from the BODY field of a node.  However, the filter for 'Limiting allowed HTML tags and correct faculty HTML' needs to be left ON.

There is a certain tag I don't want added by a user but I want it to be added programmatically.  The FILTER for limiting allowed HTML keeps removing this tag even if I added it programmatically.  I assume this is because of the order of where I am programmatically adding this into.

I am trying to add it via a custom module and I would like to keep it that way if all possible and not modify at a higher level. If I cannot do it on a module, how DO I do update the BODY value after the "limited" allowed HTML tag?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create your own text filter, I found this [tutorial](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8) very helpful

Comment: @Hudri you are amazing. Thank you!